# How to vertically align a div within a div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Horizontally aligning a div-element within another div-element can be achived with `margin: 0 auto;` as long as they both have a width-property other than `auto`, but this does not apply for vertical alignment.

**How can you vertically align a div within another div?**

Comment: Check this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of different approaches to this, based on various ideas. Given that the element has a fixed height (in px, % or what have you), the best solution I've found so far is based on the following principle:

Give the parent div `position: relative;` and the child div `position: absolute;`, to make the child absolutley positioned in relation to the parent.

For the child, set `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to `0`. Given that the child also has a fixed `width` and `height` that is less than the size of the parent, this will push the browser into an impossible situation.

In comes `margin: auto;` on the child, as the browsers savior. The browser can now add enough margin on all sides to let the child-element keep its size, yet still fill out the entire parent as forced by `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` set to `0`.

**TADAAA!** The element gets vertically and horizontally aligned within the parent.

**Markup**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
​.parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**A working example**

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3Gw/

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to use `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyNxc/)

```
<style>
.a {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
<div class="a">
    <div>CENTERED</div>
</div>
​
```